# Cannot install app built on CLI, outside Android Studio – "failed to delete" errors/base.apk code missing

Tags: android, adb, aapt

I'm quite new to Android native development and lately experimenting with building directly from CLI without Android Studio (really don't like the IDE and find Gradle overly complex, although I can't get my toolchain running yet...)

Using guidance from around  the web, particularly [this](https://medium.com/@authmane512/how-to-build-an-apk-from-command-line-without-ide-7260e1e22676), I have a extremely basic app which successfully builds to a signed and aligned APK (as far as I can tell). I am building against platform 14 with Java 1.8 and I observed no changes when altering this configuration.

I've put the app source [on GitHub](https://github.com/ilmiont/android-hello-world) for reference for this question. It's one activity with one layout.

When it comes to `adb install` (or manually install from the device), installation always fails with `INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK`... `Package /data/app/net.ilmiont.helloworld-...==/base.apk code is missing` (`...` is some long ID by appearances).

**Logcat**

Running `adb logcat` during the installation attempt, I get this:

`11-16 10:34:52.729 24742  7402 I Finsky  : [9791] com.google.android.finsky.verifier.impl.ea.a(82): Skipping verification. Disabled by user setting
11-16 10:34:52.729 24742  7402 I Finsky  : [9791] com.google.android.finsky.verifier.impl.ea.a(43): Skipping anti malware verification due to pre-check failure
11-16 10:34:52.730 24742 24742 I Finsky  : [2] com.google.android.finsky.verifier.impl.fs.c(164): Verifying id=132, result=1
11-16 10:34:52.735 24742 24742 I Finsky  : [2] com.google.android.finsky.verifier.impl.fs.c(177): Verification complete: id=132, package_name=net.ilmiont.helloworld
11-16 10:34:52.752  1856 27782 E         : Couldn't opendir /data/data/net.ilmiont.helloworld: No such file or directory
11-16 10:34:52.753  1856 27782 E installd: Failed to delete /data/data/net.ilmiont.helloworld: No such file or directory
11-16 10:34:52.753  1856 27782 E         : Couldn't opendir /data/user_de/0/net.ilmiont.helloworld: No such file or directory
11-16 10:34:52.753  1856 27782 E installd: Failed to delete /data/user_de/0/net.ilmiont.helloworld: No such file or directory
11-16 10:34:52.754  2198  2398 W PackageManager: com.android.server.pm.Installer$InstallerException: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: Failed to delete /data/user_de/0/net.ilmiont.helloworld (code 2)
11-16 10:34:52.756  2198  2398 W PackageManager: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/net.ilmiont.helloworld-pbDVHiVe6mEghhiOqRUNjg==
11-16 10:34:52.756  2198  2398 W PackageManager: com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerException: Package /data/app/net.ilmiont.helloworld-pbDVHiVe6mEghhiOqRUNjg==/base.apk code is missing`

I do not understand why it is trying to open/delete these directories when the app is just getting installed (and has not ever successfully installed) --- I don't know enough about Android internals, but from that trace it does look like the deletion is the problem.

I've looked over my source multiple times and just can't see what I'm missing. The manifest looks OK, the layout looks OK, the Java is all of two lines. So what am I missing? It must be something glaringly obvious.

**The device**

This may be relevant, so here are all the details.

Nokia 6 (original one) running unrooted Android 8.1.

I opened Android Studio, created the default boilerplate app and hit "Run", and it built and deployed successfully, so clearly there is *something* wrong with my app/build toolchain which is making this break, and I've out of ideas of where to look.

**The build script (excerpts, it does build but will not deploy)**

`aapt package -v -f -m -J $PROJECT_SOURCE -M $ANDROID_MANIFEST -S $ANDROID_RESOURCES -I $ANDROID_SDK/platforms/android-$ANDROID_API/android.jar;`

`javac -d $JAVA_COMPILE_DESTINATION -source $JAVA_VERSION -target $JAVA_VERSION_TARGET -classpath "$PROJECT_SOURCE$JAVA_CLASSPATH_LIBS" -bootclasspath $ANDROID_SDK/platforms/android-$ANDROID_API/android.jar $PROJECT_SOURCE/$PROJECT_PACKAGE_SOURCE/*.java;`

`dx --dex --output=$DX_COMPILE_DESTINATION $JAVA_COMPILE_DESTINATION;`

`aapt package -f -m -F $APP_APK_UNALIGNED -M $ANDROID_MANIFEST -S $ANDROID_RESOURCES -I $ANDROID_SDK/platforms/android-$ANDROID_API/android.jar;`

`aapt add $APP_APK_UNALIGNED $DX_COMPILE_DESTINATION;`

`zipalign -f 4 $APP_APK_UNALIGNED $APP_APK;`

`apksigner sign --ks /home/jh_walker/.keystore $APP_APK;`

**Keystore**

`keytool -genkeypair -validity 365 -keystore $KEYSTORE -alias $KEYSTORE_ALIAS -sigalg SHA1withDSA -keyalg DSA -keysize 1024`

**What I've tried**

- Java 1.7/1.8
- Compiling against different Android platforms (21/28)
- Including additional assets (didn't have icons originally)
- Setting `use-sdk` in the manifest (no impact)

***What am I missing?***

Answer (score 3):

I got there.

`aapt inspect app.apk`

And immediately I noticed in the APK, was `./bin/classes.dex`, and none of the other files had that `./` prefix.

Digging deeper, and I saw in my build script I was compiling DEX to `./bin/classes.dex`, and then adding that path to my APK. But it appears something about that path wasn't liked by `aapt` (although it's entirely valid for where I was running it from), and it didn't properly add the file --- it seems just some empty `./bin/classes.dex` it made up.

(Yes that's a kinda pathetic explanation, and I'll investigate properly later!)

Anyway, it seems you have to add from your current directory: `classes.dex`. Maybe this is obvious to someone more familiar with the tools.

Anyway,

`cp ./bin/classes.dex . && aapt add app.apk.unaligned classes.dex` works, but `aapt add app.apk.unaligned ./bin/classes.dex` does not .

Comment: You saved me. `aapt` not linking paths outside the current working directory is the strangest behavior…

Answer (score 0):

If this somehow happens to you when you want to install a debug (`gradle installDebug`) version of your App in your device, check that `versionCode` and `versionName` are not changed from the last release published to the Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the `base.apk code is missing` error message when attempting to install the apk on my device. In my case, I had recently upgraded Gradle and Android Gradle tools (naively because Studio recommended it).... So, downgrading to the previous gradle and tools version fixed it for me.

Downgrading can be done by editing the version numbers in 2 locations: `android/build.gradle` and `gradle-wrapper.properties` - and then doing a gradle sync in Android Studio.